# iOS : Cannot click the right side of UINavigationItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

```
-(void )SetNavBarView{
    searchBarBtn.hidden=YES;

    UIView *NavBarView  ;
    NavBarView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

    UIButton *btn1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
    btn1.titleLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    [btn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [btn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nine_grid.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn1.tag=10;
    [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBarClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [NavBarView addSubview:btn1];


    UIButton *btn2 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 0, 44, 44)];
    btn2.titleLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    [btn2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn2.tag=11;
    [btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBarClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [NavBarView addSubview:btn2];



    UILabel *labtitle=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(95, 0, 120, 44)];
    labtitle.text=NSLocalizedString(@"people_nearby", nil);
    labtitle.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    labtitle.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    labtitle.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
    labtitle.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
    [NavBarView addSubview:labtitle];



    UIButton *btn3 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(135, 0, 95, 44)];
    btn3.tag=12;
    [btn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBarClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [NavBarView addSubview:btn3];

    arrowImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 16, 10, 10)];
    arrowImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_down.png"];//arrow_down.png
    [btn3 addSubview:arrowImage];

    UIButton *btn4 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 0, 44, 44)];
    btn4.titleLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

    [btn4 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_action_search.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn4.tag=13;
    [btn4 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBarClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [NavBarView addSubview:btn4];


//    [bubble stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:20 topCapHeight:14]
    UIButton *btn5 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(275, 0, 44, 44)];
    btn5.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [btn5 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"location.png" ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     btn5.tag=14;
    [btn5 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBarClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [NavBarView addSubview:btn5];

    NavBarView.hidden=NO;

//    [self.view addSubview:NavBarView];
    self.navigationItem.titleView=NavBarView;


}
```

I have a `UINavigationItem` , which has five  buttons. The fifth button `btn5` can only click the left side, but the right of the `btn5` cannot be clicked. ( Size of the button is 44 x 44 )

Comment: are you sure bcoz i have used your code and it work perfectlly.

Comment: btn5 x: 275- 319 if you click the x :305-319 i think the btn5 not click

Comment: it seems to me the titleview width smaller than your yiur view u trying to add ??

Comment: my code is CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)

Comment: you means when you click on red area than it not response , but img giving response right.

Comment: the red area is from 275-319,the 275-305 i can click,but when i click the 305-319,it not response,i need all area can response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the size of UINavigationBarItem, it will by default leave a 14px around both sides. If you give a background color to your first button, then you see that space.

Comment: i receive your answer,but how to remove the leaving space around 14px both side

Comment: I have checked on google but i cant find any data on that,either not on apple site,so i suggest you to put question on stack so anyone that knew any heck method than we can do it.

Comment: but when i give the bth5 red color,it not leaving space around 14px both side，it is 44*44,but not response on the right

Comment: i think its bcoz you are giving your view width 320 so it will display outside the tabbaritem.